# Java 2D array into 2D ArrayList with stream

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

So I have an `Integer[][] data` that I want to convert into an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, so I tried using streams and came up with the following line:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> col = Arrays.stream(data).map(i -> Arrays.stream(i).collect(Collectors.toList())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>::new));
```

But the last part `collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>::new))` gives me an error that it cannot convert `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to C`.

Comment: If you don't need a specific `List` implementation, you can do `List<List<Integer>> col = Arrays.stream(data).map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @AlexisC. this should be the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner `collect(Collectors.toList()` returns a `List<Integer>`, not `ArrayList<Integer>`, so you should collect these inner `List`s into an `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` :

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> col = 
    Arrays.stream(data)
          .map(i -> Arrays.stream(i)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<List<Integer>>::new));
```

Alternately, use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new)` to collect the elements of the inner `Stream` :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> col = 
     Arrays.stream(data)
           .map(i -> Arrays.stream(i)
                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new)))
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>::new));
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it would cast List to ArrayList on it's own. Thanks!

Comment: You don’t need to write such prose at constructor references. Thanks to type inference, writing `ArrayList::new` is enough. And I wouldn’t use a stream operation for the inner array conversion, `.map(sub -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sub)))` is much simpler…