# How can I convert a 2D array to a 2D list with Streams?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-stream

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999907/java-2d-array-into-2d-arraylist-with-stream) StackOverflow answer's code, but I get the error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`:

```
//data is int[][]
Arrays.stream(data)
    .map(i -> Arrays.stream(i)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.stream` will go through each `int[]` in the `int[][]`.
You can convert an `int[]` to an `IntStream`.
Then, in order to convert a stream of `int`s to a `List<Integer>`,
you first need to box them.
Once boxed to `Integer`s, you can collect them to a list.
And finally collect the stream of `List<Integer>` into a list.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.stream(data)
    .map(row -> IntStream.of(row).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/eUjyTu)

Comment: There was no reason to change the code to `IntStream.of`; `Arrays.stream` works fine. All that was missing in the OP’s code was the call to `boxed()`…

Answer (score 1):

Try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(data).map(a -> IntStreamEx.of(a).boxed().toList()).toList();
```

Or [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common), simple and most efficient:

```
Stream.of(data).map(a -> IntList.of(a).boxed()).toList();

// Or:
Seq.of(data).map(a -> IntList.of(a).boxed());
```

All of them are null safety. An empty list is returned if `data` is null